# jQuery :disabled selector not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="text1" value="text1">
    <input type="text" id="text2" value="text2" disabled>
    <input type="text" id="text3" value="text3" readonly>
</form>
```

I want to add *ui-state-disabled* class to all disabled inputs, I use:

```
$('form input:disabled').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

However, text3 doesn't get the class. How can I change my selector to include it? (Because readonly is the same as disabled in my application requirments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an attribute selector

```
$('form input:disabled, form :input[readonly]').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yQem9/)